# Building C++11 iOS console app from command line

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, jailbreak

I am trying to build a simple C++ console app for jailbroken iOS device.
I use the following command:

```
`xcrun --sdk iphoneos --find g++` -std=c++14 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk -arch armv7 -arch armv7s -arch arm64 -c main.cpp
```

It compiles without errors.

But I cannot use c++11 features like chrono dispite '-std=c++14' passed:
[image: chrono is not available]

`chrono` header is present in iOS SDK: `../iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1`.

I use XCode Version 9.2 (9C40b), macOS 10.12.6 (16G1710)

Comment: If you do `\`xcrun --sdk iphoneos --find g++\` -v`, what do you get?

Comment: @NathanOliver, I get `g++: /usr/bin/xcode-select failed: Undefined error: 0` because there is no xcode-select utility. I might accidentally deleted it when tried to get rid of an old XCode. Is it can be related to the issue?

Can you compile a similar app on your system? If you can please tell me version of your XCode. I am going to reinstall my system anyways.